# Show all products when search is empty or blank Opencart 2.3.x

Tags: php, opencart2.x, opencart2.3

I recently started using OpenCart. When I use the search option on OpenCart with an empty or blank keyword it searches for "" which yields 0 results.

Is it possible to get all products on the site when user types an empty or blank search keyword?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check the file catalog/controller/product/search.php and check the condition in index() function

```
if ($this->request->get['search'] == '')
```

For above condition's true block, you can remove **'filter_name'** index from **$filter_data** array and you can reuse the code needed to get products.